# Is it possible to hide Google Map but keep Search Bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm trying to create a homepage with only a search bar that is a Google Places search bar. I want to then display the google map results on the next page along with the city they searched.

I have only found examples of how to hide the search box and UI of the google map.

Is there a way to use google maps & places api but hide the map and keep the search functionality from the search box?

Comment: can you use display:none?

Comment: The SearchBox doesn't require a `google.maps.Map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `google.maps.Map` object to use the [Places SearchBox](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#SearchBox)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#pac-input {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-left: 12px;
  padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 300px;
}
#pac-input:focus {
  border-color: #4d90fe;
}
.pac-container {
  font-family: Roboto;
}
#type-selector {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4d90fe;
  padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
}
#type-selector label {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
#target {
  width: 345px;
}
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I guess I was overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the autocomplete search bar separate from the map.

See: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['places']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```